# Como obter o próximo elemento em um foreach em PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Como faço para obter o próximo elemento de um array usando foreach?

Por exemplo, estou iterando em um array e preciso saber se o próximo elemento desse array é igual ao que eu to para fazer alguma operação em relação à isso.

Comment: Cara, como assim? Explica melhor qual o caso.

Comment: Por exemplo, estou iterando em um array e preciso saber se o próximo elemento desse array é igual ao que eu to para fazer alguma operação em relação à isso.

Comment: Ah OK, vou modificar minha resposta! :)

Comment: Eu usaria um for no lugar do foreach. Aí você faz: for ($i=0; $i<$numero_elementos_do_array) { if ($array[$i] == $array[$i+1]) { comandos que você quer;} } Mas, já adianto, você deveria postar qual o problema real. Porque do jeito que você postou não tem como saber se isso funcionaria.

Comment: Você está falando de arrays numéricas, associativas, ou ambas?

Comment: Boa pergunta bfavareta, mas se ele usa um foreach, acho ele usa um array associativa. Por isso, "precisa ler array[$i+1]" não da certo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O php possui uma biblioteca interna chamada [SPL](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.spl.php) (Standard PHP Library)

Ela tem diversos objetos e interfaces que ajudam a resolver problemas comuns que encontramos.

Temos diversos [Iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/spl.iterators.php) para resolver seu problema, dois em especial: [`ArrayIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.arrayiterator.php) e [`CachingIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.cachingiterator.php)

O `ArrayIterator` cria um objeto a partir de um array com métodos para as funções como `current`, `next`, `rewind`, etc.

Já o `CachingIterator` é um iterator com "um olho no peixe e outro no gato", tendo uma posição a frente em relação ao iterator.

Dentro do `foreach` seu código ficaria assim:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    'eu'    => 'tenho', 
    'sou'   => 'keys',
    'um'    => 'para',
    'array' => 'comparar',
    'assoc' => 'galera'
];

$iterator = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($arr));

var_dump($iterator->current());                      // null
var_dump($iterator->getInnerIterator()->current());  // string(5) "tenho"

foreach($iterator as $key => $value){
    
    echo "Atual: $value - ";
    
    $proximoValue = $iterator->getInnerIterator()->current();
    echo "Proximo: $proximoValue \n";

    // Sua lógica aqui
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Com o foreach talvez não seja a melhor solução, mas pode fazer com o `each()`, que retorna o elemento atual e avança o ponteiro um elemento. Ficaria assim:

```
$arr = array("a","b","c","c","d");


while($a= each($arr)){

    //o each() avançou um e guardou o anterior
    $b = current($arr);


    if($a['value'] == $b)
    {
        echo "OK<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "NOT OK<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Um olhada no manual pode ajudar a entender melhor http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

Answer (score 2):

Simples.

Você faz o foreach normal, mas usa também um next no array para passar sempre para o próximo.

```
<?php

// Array
$itens = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');

// Lista array completo
echo "Array completo: <b>".implode(',',$itens)."</b><br /><br />";

// Percorre o array
foreach($itens as $item){
    // Exibe o item atual baseado no foreach
    echo "Item atual: <b>".$item."</b> - ";

    // Exibe o próximo item
    echo "Item Proximo: <b>".current($itens)."</b><br />";
    next($itens);
}

?>
```

Ele vai retornar.

```
Array completo: foot,bike,car,plane

Item atual: foot - Item Proximo: bike
Item atual: bike - Item Proximo: car
Item atual: car - Item Proximo: plane
Item atual: plane - Item Proximo:
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando um array básico, não tem dificuldade (precisa ler o index $x e $x+1). Mas com um array associativo (o que acho e o caso aqui) e um pouco mas complicado. Depois de pesquisar, aqui tem uma resposta:

```
<?php
$tab["A"] = 12;
$tab["B"] = 15;
$tab["C"] = 8;
$tab["D"] = 23;


foreach($tab as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Key e valor desta vez: ".$key. "-" .$value."<br>";

    $key =  key($tab);   // proximo index
    $val = $tab[$key];   // valor
    next($tab);          // avancar

    echo "Key e valor a proxima vez: ".$key."-".$val."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

O ponto estranho e que precisa colocar o next() se não, ficamos cada vez com o mesmo "próximo", como se tinha 2 index (um para o foreach e um para o key).